# Show text only for a specific custom field value in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I'm trying to display a custom text **'price only visible for logged in users'** on a single product pages, but only when the `$wpdb->postmeta`, `metafield` **`'show'`** has value **`'yes'`**, from the current **`'post_id'`**.

I can't find the right SQL query for implement the current product **post_id** when it's load the single product page.

Here is my code:

```
function show_text() {
    global $wpdb;   
    $post_id_number = get_the_id();

    $meta = $wpdb->get_results( "select * from $wpdb->wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'show' AND meta_value = 'yes'" );

    if ( $meta == TRUE ) {
        echo '<p>PRice is only visible for logged in users</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'show_text' );
```

Comment: Update: 
Trying this query, but without success:
`$meta = $wpdb->get_row( "(select * from $wpdb->wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'show' AND meta_value = 'yes') AND ( SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_posts WHERE ID = 1291 )" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use Wordpress `get_post_meta()` function this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'show_custom_text' );
function show_custom_text() {
    global $post;

    if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'show', true ) == 'yes' && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<p>PRice is only visible for logged in users</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Hi Loic, Trying the code and works very well. Thank you. That's simpler then my method :-)